# AttributeError: 'str' object has no attribute 'text' error

Tags: python, android, selenium, attributes, webdriver

Got the:
AttributeError: 'str' object has no attribute 'text' error for the following block:

```
 `version = driver.find_element_by_id('com.project.PROJECT:id/version').text
  print(version)
  for i in version:
     if 'Version : 1.2.0.133' == str(i):
         print('Step 46. NAS version is displayed correctly - PASS')
     else:
          print('Step 46. NAS version is incorrect - Fail')
 time.sleep(2)
 pass`
```

tried as well:  `if 'Version : 1.2.0.133' == i.text`

Still not working.

`print(version)` is returning the correct value: Version : 1.2.0.133

But I cannot print the `if value is true: print('Step 46. NAS version is displayed correctly - PASS')`

Is spamming me with the `else print FAIL value`

Also if I use the `.text` for EC waiting will return an error as well.

Thank you

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I believe `driver.find_element_by_id('com.project.PROJECT:id/version')` returns a `str` object, which doesn't have a `.text` attribute. Try removing `.text` from the first line in your code.

Comment: I added `.text` to print the value (it worked) but it won't work for the iteration.
I removed `.text` and left the iteration as it is and is working.
Thank you

Answer (score 5):

I believe your `version` variable is a string, so when you write

```
for i in version:
     if 'Version : 1.2.0.133' == str(i):
         print('Step 46. NAS version is displayed correctly - PASS')
     else:
          print('Step 46. NAS version is incorrect - Fail')
```

you're actually looping through each character in the string. So `str(i)` will be a single character which will never be equal to 'Version : 1.2.0.133', so you're always falling in the else statement, printing 'Step 46. NAS version is incorrect - Fail'. This is why you get that message on loop. As far as the error mentioned in the title of your question, I'm confused as to what the problem is, since you say that `print(version)` returns the correct value.

Comment: Thanks!
That makes sense!

Comment: @Claudaette you should honour the correct answer with points by marking it as the accepted answer. Just saying

Comment: Hey @gtxtreme
I am new here and I cannot upvote answers.
Before judging please ask
And I marked the other answer as A FIX because that's the one that fixed my issue... 
Please read again before leaving a comment.
Thanks!

Comment: The suggestion was to mark the answer as correct, not necessarily this one and also not upvote and it was a suggestion